# How to post data to kinesis based on AWS login credentials in iOS objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, core-location, amazon-kinesis

I want to post the user location data to Amazon Kinesis service. I do not want to use the cognito. I have secret key and access keys. But I have no idea how to login to Amazon and post data to kinesis. Posting data to kinesis stream seems to be easy. I referred the Amazon doc for that,
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/kinesis.html

But how to send the secret key, access key and set the region before sending data to Amazon? Please help.. I am new to iOS development and have no idea how the Amazon can be accessed via these login crdentials... i searched a lot but I got only cognito releated stuffs which is of no use to me....

Answer (score 0):

Using hardcoded credentials is not recommended. If you really want to use it, try `AWSStaticCredentialsProvider` instead of `AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider`. Here is an example in this blog [Version 2 of the AWS SDK for iOS Developer Preview](https://mobile.awsblog.com/post/Tx2AA7ZHB1FK0G1/Version-2-of-the-AWS-SDK-for-iOS-Developer-Preview).

```
AWSStaticCredentialsProvider *credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider credentialsWithAccessKey:@"YourAccessKey" secretKey:@"YourSecretKey"];
AWSServiceConfiguration *configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSEast1 credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];
[AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
```